# c# web message control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, messagebox

I'm creating a community site post remover.
I have encountered a problem while completing almost all of this program, but every time I try to delete a post, I open a web message on the web and check if I really want to delete it.
[web messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FFnk.png)

Whenever the web message is displayed, press the Enter key or press the OK button with the mouse.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length;i++)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument Doc = web.Document;
                Delay(1000);//1second
                for (int q = 0; q < Doc.GetElementsByTagName("div").Count; q++)
                    if (Doc.GetElementsByTagName("div")[q].GetAttribute("article-id") == arr[i])//Only delete posts that match the article-id
                    {
                        Doc.GetElementsByTagName("div")[q].InvokeMember("Click");//Click Delete Post
                        web.Focus();
                        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");//Send Enter to web message
                    }
            }
```

I want to make that work automatic.
So I tried the following code but it did not work and I do not have any more ideas.
So, is there any way to control web messages differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...finally i solved it

first-to use control a web message box
used user32.dll and spy++

I used the user32.dll to control the web message and extracted the button value of the web message using spy ++.
The source code of the web message control using user32.dll is as follows.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx(int hWnd1, int hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public class messagebox_control
    {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x2201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

        public void Click_message()
        {
            int nhwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "웹 페이지 메시지");
            if(nhwnd>0)
            {
                int hw1 = FindWindowEx(nhwnd, 0, "DirectUIHWND", "");
                if(hw1>0)
                {
                    int hw2 = FindWindowEx(hw1, 0, "CtrlNotifySink", "");
                    if(hw2>0)
                    {
                        while(true)
                        {
                            int hw3 = FindWindowEx(hw2, 0, "Button", "확인");
                            if (hw3>0)
                            {
                                SendMessage(hw3, BM_CLICK, 0, 1);
                                break;
                            }
                            hw2 = FindWindowEx(hw1, hw2, "CtrlNotifySink", "");
                            if (hw2==0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But that code does not work. This is because the thread is suspended at the moment the web message pops up.
So, as soon as I started the program with multithreading, I kept running the above code and it worked fine.